# how to join room to websocket server in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I wrote websocket client in Javascript before and it works well. I want to write similar code in Python.

What I don't know is how to write to join a room.

My javascript code is the following.

```
socket = io.connect(SOCK_HOST);
room = localStorage.getItem("consultation_id");
socket.on("server_to_client", function(data){socket_client(data.value)});
socket.emit("join_room", {value : room});

message = "ack_webview";
socket.emit("client_to_server", {value : message});
```

My python script is the following.

```
socket = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCK_HOST, on_message = on_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close)
room = consultation_id
socket.on("server_to_client", function(data){socket_client(data.value)});
socket.send("join_room", {value : room});

message = 'payment_finished'
socket.send('client_to_server', {value : message})
```

I believe websocket module in python doesn't have emit function. So I have no idea how can I send the 2 kind of message('client_to_server' and message) to the server.

Please give me an advice.